# viewDidLoad() is running before Alamofire request in prepareforsegue has a chance to finish

Tags: ios, swift, segue, alamofire

I have two viewControllers that are giving me trouble. One is called `notificationAccessViewController.swift` and the other is called `classChooseViewController.swift`. I have a button in the `notificationAccessViewController` that triggers a segue to the `classChooseViewController`. What I need to do is within the `prepareForSegue` function, perform an `Alamofire` request and then pass the response to the `classChooseViewController`. That works! BUT, not fast enough.

Below is my `prepareForSegue` function within the `notificationAccessViewController`

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let DestViewController = segue.destination as! classChooseViewController
    Alamofire.request("MYURL.com").responseJSON { (response) in
        if let JSON : NSDictionary = response.result.value as! NSDictionary?{
            let classNameArray = JSON["className"] as! NSArray
            print("---")
            print(classNameArray)
            DestViewController.classNameArray = classNameArray
        }
    }
}
```

I have it printing out `classNameArray` to the console, which it does SUCCESSFULLY. Although, in my `classChooseViewController.swift`, I also print out the `classNameArray` to the console and it prints with nothing inside of it. This is because the `viewDidLoad()` function of the `classChooseViewController.swift` is running before the `prepareForSegue` function has finished. I want to know what I can do to ensure that the `classChooseViewController` does not load until the `prepareForSegue` function has FINISHED running.

Below is my code for `classChooseViewController`

```
class classChooseViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
var classNameArray: NSArray = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(classNameArray)
    }
}
```

I have attached a picture of what the console reads. You can see that the `classNameArray` prints from the `classChooseViewController`s `viewDidLoad()` function BEFORE the `prepareForSegue()` function because the "---" prints out after.

[image: Console Printout Screenshot]

Comment: You should load the data in the destination view controller, not the source.

Comment: @Paulw11 That is what I had setup originally. Although, in the 'classChooseViewController, I have a UITableView which I need to populate with the data from the array that I get from the Alamofire request. When I perform the request in the view controller, the UITableView has already loaded and I cannot use the array that I get from the alamofire request to populate it.

Comment: Yes, you can. You should display some indication to the user that the data is being loaded, a spinner or "loading"  cell and then reload the table once you have the data.

Comment: Would you suggest I hide the UITableView by default, display a loading indicator (spinner), then once the data is ready show the UITableView once again?

Comment: Yes. That is one approach. The other method I have used is to have a single cell "loading" or similar in the table if the source array is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design is wrong.

The Alamofire `request` function is asynchronous. It returns immediately, before the results are ready. Then it invokes the completion handler that you pass in.

I tend to agree with Paul that you should make the request in the destination view controller, not in the current view controller.

If you DO want to fetch the data in Alamofire before you segue to the other view controller then you'll need to write a method that starts the request, then invokes the segue to the other view controller from the `Alamofire.request()` call's completion handler.

If you're invoking the new view controller from a button press, you need to not link the button directly to a segue, but instead write an IBAction method that triggers the AlamoFire request call, then invokes the segue (or instantiates the view controller directly and pushes/presents it manually) from the completion handler.

Something like this:

```
@IBAction buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
  Alamofire.request("MYURL.com").responseJSON { 
    (response) in
    if let JSON : NSDictionary = response.result.value as! NSDictionary? {
      let classNameArray = JSON["className"] as! NSArray
        print("---")
        print(classNameArray)
        let theClassChooseViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"ClassChooseViewController" as ClassChooseViewController
        theClassChooseViewController.classNameArray = classNameArray
        presentViewController(theClassChooseViewController, 
          animated: true,
          completion: nil)
     }
  }
}
```

By the way, class names and types should start with an upper case letter, and variable names should start with a lower-case letter. This is a very strong convention in both Swift and Objective-C, and you'll confuse the hell out of other iOS/Mac developers unless you follow the convention.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried implimenting this IBAction method; although I am getting a few errors. [link](http://imgur.com/a/ZaxKX)

@DuncanC

Comment: I found the error to be nothing more than a missing close-parenthesis. Although, even after fixing that two other errors remain. One on the line 
`let classChooseViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"ClassChooseViewController") as! classChooseViewController` 
The error reads implicit use of 'self.' use self. to make capture semantics explicit

Comment: I typed out that Code in the stack  overflow editor. It almost certainly has multiple syntax errors. It was not intended to be copy and pastedit into your code. It was only meant as a guide.

Comment: See if you can fix that "implicit use of self" error yourself. If you look closely Xcode tells you exactly what to do to fix it.

Comment: Duncan, I was able to fix both of the "implicit use of self" errors. Although, when I clicked the button, triggering the IBAction, I get a "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" error and the view does not change. Do I need to make a segue between the two viewControllers for the presentViewController() function to work?

Comment: In the terminal, it says that 'Stordboard doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'classChooseViewController''. I have triple checked that the spelling matches up. Is it possible that I am checking the wrong Story board?

Comment: If you're going to use `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` then you have to go into IB and assign a Storyboard ID to the scene in the "Identity Inspector."